# He died after he was ill for a long time

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, simple-past-vs-past-perfect

> (14) He died after he had been ill for a long time. 
> (15) She told me his name after he had left.

In a 1989 paper titled "[Perfect and pluperfect: What is the relationship?](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/231904059_Perfect_and_pluperfect_What_is_the_relationship1)", Raphael Salkie discussed the above pair in the following paragraph:

> If the pluperfect in (14) is replaced by a past (*...after he was ill for a long time*), the result is bizarre, as Bouscaren *et al.* note (1982b: 77). (14) indicates that the illness was relevant to his death - it is natural to infer that it was in fact the cause of it. **Using the past tense instead suggests that the speaker is not asserting any relevance relation between the two events, but in
> that case, why mention the illness at all, let alone in a subordinate clause straight after mentioning the death?** In (15) the relevance relation indicated by using the pluperfect suggests that she deliberately waited until he was out of the room before revealing his name. Substituting the simple past (*...after
> he left*) does not, however, lead to strangeness in this instance; the subordinate clause in this case merely functions as a temporal anchor to let us know when the name disclosure took place, without the idea of deliberately waiting. As Bouscaren *et al.* point out (1982: 77), the relation between the two events is stronger in (14) than in (15). It would be odd to just use the illness as a temporal anchor given the close relation between the illness and dying; hence the oddness of (14) with the simple past.

Let me show the simple past version of (14) again:

> (14') He died after he was ill for a long time.

According to the cited paragraph, particularly the boldfaced portion, Salkie seems to be saying that (14') is bizarre because we can't normally think of a context where the illness itself does not lead to his death. But I think I can think of such a context. For example, an old man could have died after suffering for a long time from a chronic but non-terminal disease that did not have any relevance in his death. In this context, the speaker might want to add the information about him being ill for a long time just to convey the idea that he wasn't free from disease before his death.

Does this mean that (14') might work in such a context?

Comment: The usual expression is _He died after a long illness._ Other versions sound distinctly odd.

Comment: The article says it's bizarre but could apply in special contexts. So yes, it does say what you think it says. I'm not sure if "Yes you're right!" merits an answer but maybe someone can turn it into a useful answer.

Comment: 'He got married after he was in Canada for several years' also sounds unnatural, and it is surely just sequential rather than in any way causal.

Comment: To me, (14') sounds correct, even if the illness *did* cause his death. American English in particular sometimes allows describing "relevant" past events without using the perfect; that said, intuitions on this can vary widely between speakers, so others may disagree.

Comment: A good example of this variation is the sentence "I'm not hungry; I already ate." Most American speakers will find this acceptable, but at least some British speakers would prefer "I've already eaten."

Comment: @KateBunting: I find *He died after being ill for a long time* acceptable, as well. But the simple past and past perfect sound a little off to me.

Comment: The author says (14) using the past simple is odd not that it is ungrammatical. Anything in English can be said, as long as the word order is respected, to be grammatical or an example of a dialect.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A Orwell's Sixth is often regarded as a rule superseding grammaticality. Grammatical sentences can still lose marks in essays, being considered unacceptable on other grounds. And grammar eventually shifts to accommodate practice.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth so... you're agreeing with me? Could we also say **After he was ill for years, he died** (?)

Comment: @Mari-LouA I don't even find it odd. To me "was ill" and "had been ill" seem equally acceptable there.

Comment: Both *He died after he had been ill for a long time* and *He died after he was ill for a long time* are unnatural: He didn’t die after he was ill; he died while he was ill.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I find 'He died after he had been ill for a long time' rather strange, perhaps too abrupt, probably because causality is doubtless involved. I find 'He died after he was ill for a long time' at least bordering on the unacceptable. I'd use 'After being ill for a long time, he died' most natural. Salkie has, I believe, brought to light fine points of usage.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth If you agree with Salkie, what's your answer to the question?

Comment: It's a very contrived context, but 'His later like could hardly be called pleasant. (14') He died after he was ill for a long time.' is arguably passable. But it's not good style. // I'm agreeing with Salkie's pointing out of this phenomenon; I'm still working on the rationale behind it. Certainly sentences like 'The earthquake was tragic, and there's pizza for tea' are totally grammatical, totally decipherable (contrast 'Colorless green ...'), but unacceptable (or extremely quirky) because of dissonance.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Thanks. I don't like (14') very much either. But I don't see how my suggested context is contrived when there are certainly many people who die a natural death after suffering from a long illness that is totally unrelated to their death. It's just that their health span is much shorter than their lifespan.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don't understand what you mean by that. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Ran out of time //// The licensing of the literary context, not the situation! (Many sentences that sound unnatural in isolation can be made to sound almost normal with well chosen [usually prior] context.) //  'He went to America after he lived in Africa for a long time' sounds equally off, and there's no hint of causality there.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Isn't your last example a counterexample of Salkie's reasoning behind the oddity of (14')?

Comment: I'd say so. I'm agreeing with Salkie that the phenomenon is real, not totally with his analysis.

Answer (score 1):

The past perfect ***had been** ill* implies a retrospective view, a *looking back upon* the illness.

> She had been ill for a long time.

The illness might still be ongoing (*She had been ill for a long time and wondered if she would ever get better*) or it might have ended (*She had been ill for a long time, and so we were not surprised to get the news that she had passed*) but the attitude towards the state or condition mentioned in the pp clause is retrospective.

**After** yoked to a retrospective view is an odd coupling. It's like trying to grab the hair of Lady Opportunity if she were looking back over her shoulder. Opportunity is bald in the back.

Compare: *I drank a lot of water after I had been thirsty.<sup>bizarre</sup>

> I was working out in the hot sun and had brought no water with me. Man, was I ever thirsty! When I got home that evening, I drank a lot of water after I had been thirsty.

Or this oddity:

> I opened my umbrella after it had been raining.

Which we can make normal:

> I opened my umbrella after it had been raining for some time.

or

> I opened my umbrella only after it had been raining for some time.

I delayed opening my umbrella.

Bizarre or normal depends on which way Lady Opportunity's head is facing. **After** on the semantic level requires a fixed moment in time.

Comment: Are you saying that (14) is odd?

Comment: **for a long time** keeps (14) from being odd as **for some time** keeps my umbrella sentence from being odd. If you remove that temporal modifier, it becomes odd in the way *I drank a lot of water after I had been thirsty* is odd.

Comment: *I painted the wall green after it had been blue* is odd. *I painted the wall green after it had been blue for about ten years* is not odd; the temporal phrase gives the open-ended state of blueness the sort of finiteness that **after** requires.